# Change field of json in element of array only if condition is true

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

all.
I am trying to change the value of field in element of array in json with condition: if value of "field1" equals "value1", then change value of field "changethisfield" to "new_value".
Current payload:

```
    {
      "message": [
        {
          "field1": "value1",
          "field2": "value2",
          "changethisfield": ""
        },
        {
          "field1": "value3",
          "field2": "value4",
          "changethisfield": ""
        }
      ]
    }
```

Dataweave code:

```
    %dw 2.0
    output application/json

    var itemValue = payload.message map (item) -> {
        (item mapObject (value, key, index) -> {
            ((key): value) if (key as String != 'changethisfield'),
            (changethisfield: "new_value") if (key as String == 'changethisfield')
        })
    }

    ---

    {
        "message": {
            item: itemValue
        }
    }
```

But this code changes value in all elements of array (**current output**):

```
{
  "message": {
    "item": [
      {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "changethisfield": "new_value"
      },
      {
        "field1": "value3",
        "field2": "value4",
        "changethisfield": "new_value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Desired output** (only value of "changethisfield" item where "field1" contains "value1" should change to "new_value"):

```
{
  "message": {
    "item": [
      {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "changethisfield": "new_value"
      },
      {
        "field1": "value3",
        "field2": "value4",
        "changethisfield": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please, help to understand how I can make conditions in elements of array and solve this task. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wanted to add that you can also use the `update` function instead of removing a re-adding the field to the object manually. This will work to change every item in the array to a specific value as well but since you had the condition, you have to perform it inside a map.

The issue with your comparison is that you did the comparison as the object level and only if a key was a specific string. You're not checking if field1 has a certain value or not.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::util::Values

var inputData =     {
      "message": [
        {
          "field1": "value1",
          "field2": "value2",
          "changethisfield": ""
        },
        {
          "field1": "value3",
          "field2": "value4",
          "changethisfield": ""
        }
      ]
    }

---
{
    message: inputData.message map ((item, index) -> (
        if (item.field1 == "value1") (
            item update "changethisfield" with "newValue"
        ) else (
            item
        )
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw

var data =     {
      "message": [
        {
          "field1": "value1",
          "field2": "value2",
          "changethisfield": ""
        },
        {
          "field1": "value3",
          "field2": "value4",
          "changethisfield": ""
        }
      ]
    }

---
message: data.message map {
    ($ - "changethisfield"),
    changethisfield: if ($.field1 == "value1") "new_value" else $.changethisfield
}
```